# disable stormpath's Create account option in the login screen

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

I want to disable the create account in the stormpath login screen. The call to the api should already be made from a user authenticated to the app. I tried setting stormpathEnableRegistration to false but the registration functionality is still enabled.

```
  app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
     apiKeyFile: config.stormpathapi.apiKeyFile,
     application: config.stormpathapi.application,
     secretKey: config.stormpathapi.secretKey,
     sessionDuration: 1000 * 60 * 30,
     enableAutoLogin: true,
     enableUsername: true,
     stormpathEnableRegistration: false
  }));
```

Thanks!

Comment: This was posted 8 months ago, the other question 6 months ago @mikemaccana but thanks

Comment: Sorry Will! I've marked the newer question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of the `express-stormpath` library, sorry this was confusing.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Rename `stormpathEnableRegistration` -> `enableRegistration`.
2. Update to the latest release of the library.

I just pushed a change in the latest release which fixes a rendering issue on the login page when this setting is disabled. What used to be happening was this:

- You'd disable registration.
- The registration page wouldn't work.
- But the login page would still render a 'Create Account' link.

In the latest release this is fixed =)

**UPDATE**: Since the 2.x.x release of express-stormpath is now out, the above information is no longer valid. Instead, you should do this:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  client: {
    apiKey: {
      file: config.stormpathapi.apiKeyFile
    }
  },
  application: {
    href: config.stormpathapi.application
  },
  web: {
    register: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}));
```

This will disable the registration functionality for you =)

Comment: As of the 2.x release of express-stormpath, you now need to do this a bit different. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes. See the UPDATE section above.